# Do I need to create @Module when I use dependency injection for only one implementation of an interface?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I'm reading the article [Using Hilt in your Android app](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#7).

Both Code A and Code B are from the [sample project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-hilt) in solution branch.

The `AppNavigatorImpl` is only one implementation of the interface `AppNavigator`, and Android Studio also prompt *"Class NavigationModule" is never used* in Code B, you can see Image B.

So I think Hilt can create the instance of `AppNavigatorImpl` automatically.

But I get the following error when I remove Code B from the project, why?

*com.example.android.hilt.navigator.AppNavigator cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method*

**Code A**

```
interface AppNavigator {   
    fun navigateTo(screen: Screens)
}


class AppNavigatorImpl @Inject constructor(private val activity: FragmentActivity) : AppNavigator {
   ...
}


@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject lateinit var navigator: AppNavigator
    ...

}
```

**Code B**

```
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class NavigationModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindNavigator(impl: AppNavigatorImpl): AppNavigator
}
```

**Image B**

[image]

Comment: You need it. Even tho `AppNavigationImpl` can be constructed automagically, it will never be recognized as `AppNavigation` interface (which is what you're using - and injecting - in your code) in the dependency graph without a binding module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It requires use of module since you are using interface injection in activity. Code will use the module once you rebuild the project. I guess, IDE is showing the module class as not used before rebuilding the project.